# bash: /home/vishal/.bashrc: Errors when opening terminal

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, bashrc

Everytime I open my terminal , this message pops up. Please tell how to permanently delete this from the terminal?

```
bash: export: `=': not a valid identifier
bash: export: `/home/vishal/LLVM/llvm-project-llvmorg-12.0.0/build/bin': not a valid identifier\
C: command not found\
C: command not found\
C: command not found\
C: command not found\
D: command not found\
bash: /home/vishal/.bashrc: line 140: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
bash: /home/vishal/.bashrc: line 141: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

[image]

Last line of the file `~/.bashrc`:

```
export PATH= "/home/vishal/LLVM/llvm-project-llvmorg-12.0.0/build/bin"
```

Comment: You have errors in your `~/.bashrc`. If you show the output of this command (in text) in your question, we might be able to identify the errors: `cat /home/vishal/.bashrc`.

Comment: bash: export: `/home/vishal/LLVM/llvm-project-llvmorg-12.0.0/build/bin': not a valid identifier
vishal@vishal1005:~$ cat /home/vishal/.bashrc
bash: cat: No such file or directory. This is what I got.

Comment: Oh you messed up your path - awesome. Use absolute path then: `/usr/bin/cat /home/vishal/.bashrc`. By the look of your error messages, it seems you forgot a closing quote somewhere in `~/.bashrc`.

Comment: export PATH= "/home/vishal/LLVM/llvm-project-llvmorg-12.0.0/build/bin"
This is the last line of the terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what info you have provided so far, it's evident that the last line of your `~/.bashrc` is invalid.

Run this command to edit the file:

```
/usr/bin/nano /home/vishal/.bashrc
```

This line should be changed to: *(remove the space after `=` and add `:$PATH`)*

```
export PATH="/home/vishal/LLVM/llvm-project-llvmorg-12.0.0/build/bin:$PATH"
```

[See here](https://www.nano-editor.org/dist/latest/cheatsheet.html) for Nano's default keyboard shortcuts.

Always include `:$PATH` at the end of new `PATH` exports - else you'll overwrite everything else in the path.

It's possible your `~/.bashrc` contains other errors as well.

Comment: Thanks for helping me out as I am new to linux. It worked. Got to understand a lot of things as well.

Comment: Happy to hear it worked. If you experience other errors in `~/.bashrc`, please edit your question and include the entire `~/.bashrc` - then we can probably find the errors. Thanks!